# Is merging branch A into B same as merging B into A?

Tags: git

In a git repository, is *merging branch **A** into **B*** same as *merging **B** into **A***?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, if you merge A into B, then in the end branch A will only have A's changes, and B will have both A+B changes.

If you merge B into A, then A with have both A+B changes, and B will only have B's changes.

Start:

```
 /A1-A2-A3
X 
 \B1-B2-B3
```

A to B with a merge commit:

```
 /A1-A2-A3
X 
 \B1-B2-B3-A*(1,2,3)
```

A to B with fast forward:

```
 /A1-A2-A3
X 
 \A1-A2-A3-B1'-B2'-B3'
```

B to A with merge commit:

```
 /A1-A2-A3-B*(B1,B2,B3)
X 
 \B1-B2-B3
```

B to A with fast forward:

```
 /B1-B2-B3-A1'-A2'-A3'
X 
 \B1-B2-B3
```

Comment: Right, so the resultant (merged) branch will be exactly the same in both cases?

Comment: After the merge, both branches still exist.

Comment: And as you can see from my diagrams, in each case the destination branch ends up with a different set of changes in its history.

Comment: you have not answered this question:
`Right, so the resultant (merged) branch will be exactly the same in both cases?`

Comment: I mean, imagine these two:
1. merge A into B and look at the result 
2. merge B into A and look at the result

Are the results the two bove the same? (Forget about parents, just the resulted chages )

Comment: @Kasra a branch is more than the set of files at the head. It is also all of the history of commits preceding the head.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder you are right. But just to be explicit, the set of files at the head of A after merging B into A would be exactly the same as the set of files at the head of B after merging A into B, correct?

Comment: Yes, the set of files will be the same (modulo problems with the merge / git bugs etc).

Comment: @Kasra We often do ‘1. merge A into B and look at the result 2. merge B into A and look at the result Are the results the two bove the same?’ since we merge master into feature-branch,  then feature-branch into master. When this is done both branches are identical since they have the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept called `first parent` when the merge generate a new merge commit.
You can check the parents of a merge commit by command `git show merge-commit-hash`, replace the `merge-commit-hash` with the real commit hash.
And you will get something like following:

> commit [commit]
>   Merge: [parent1] [parent2]

Assume you have following commits history, C1 is the parent of C2 and C3. And branch A points to C2, branch B points to C3.

> C1<--C2
>      \<--C3

When you merge branch A(C2) into branch B(C3), the first parent commit would be C3.
When you merge branch B(C3) into branch A(C2), the first parent commit would be C2.

You can check it with my [demo project](https://github.com/ChuckGitMerge/first-parent). And you can check the log graph with TortoiseGit.
[Walk Behaviour → First Parent](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html) just follow up first parent commit. This will help understand overwhole history.